# List and install older unison version through OS X brew

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew, osx-el-capitan

I'm trying to get unison to sync files between my new OS X el capitan MBP and my work computer running ubuntu 14.04. When I run my sync profile I get a the following traceback 
`Fatal error: Received unexpected header from the server:
 expected "Unison 2.48\n" but received "Unison 2.40\n\000\000\000\000\017",
which differs at "Unison 2.40".
This can happen because you have different versions of Unison
installed on the client and server machines, or because
your connection is failing and somebody is printing an error
message, or because your remote login shell is printing
something itself before starting Unison.`

Based on [this site](http://www.mtsoukalos.eu/install-older-homebrew-package) It problem appears to be solved by changing to an earlier version of unison.  Unfortunately, The specifics of this approach are no longer valid because

`` Error: The `versions` command is no longer supported.
You can use the homebrew-versions tap instead:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions
Or use `brew log` to browse the git history. ``

If I then do `brew tap homebrew-versions` I get `Error: Invalid tap name`

How should I attempt the advice on the referenced website (finding and reverting to the appropriate unison version for el capitan) with `Homebrew 0.9.5 (git revision 0f0c; last commit 2015-10-16)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I got my local install via Homebrew to Unison 2.40:

```
brew uninstall unison
brew install homebrew/versions/unison240
```

Comment: `~$ brew install homebrew/versions/unison240
Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.` -- any ideas?

Comment: @emdee https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/unison check this out

Answer (score 1):

I think the brew package you're looking for is `brew tap homebrew/versions`.

There are also Mac binary packages for Unison 2.40 available [here](http://alan.petitepomme.net/unison/index.html).